# I want to be directed to my compilation errors in visual studio (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am using VS community 2017 (MS Visual C++).

When I compile my project, it shows me the compilation output in the VS's console.

When I have compilation errors, it indicates the file and line of the error, in the VS's console.

But I wish the VS automatically redirected me to that file/line if I click on the error.

Obviously, it doesn't do anything after I click, because it is just a plain text console.

I'm sure there has to be a way to click on the errors and get directed to the code.

I'm tired of looking up my errors manually!

Thanks!!!

Comment: Are you looking for "Error List"? It does just that..

Comment: The errors tab does this. Although with that said I still prefer the Output Tab.

Comment: Are you using the IDE or compiling at the command line?

Comment: double clicking a line in the output window should take you to the right location

Answer (score 6):

Visual studio has this built in.  If you double click on the error in the error list it will take you to the file and line the error is for.

[image: Error list]

For example you would double click in the area inside the circle and it will take you to that error.

You can even get this in the output window if you double click on the error line

[image: Build Output]